# Como enviar um parâmetro do JavaScript para o Python?

Tags: javascript, html, python

Como eu envio um parâmetro para ser lido por uma função no Python?

Tenho a seguinte função em Python:

```py
@app.route("/add")
def add(book_id):
    """Atribui o ID de um livro ao ID do usuário"""
    db.execute("""
        INSERT INTO reading (user_id, book_id, price)
        VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :book_id, :price)
        """,
        user_id = session["user_id"],
        book_id = book_id,
        price = 20 # TODO
    )
    return redirect("/")
```

Para chegar a esta função eu utilizo o seguinte script:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var cover, title, author;

function handleResponse(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    var item = response.items[i];
    // Cria elementos
    figure = document.createElement("figure");
    add = document.createElement("a");
    img = document.createElement("img");
    figcap = document.createElement("figcaption");
    // Recebe dados do JSON
    try {
      cover = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
      title = item.volumeInfo.title;
      author = item.volumeInfo.authors;
    } catch (error) {
      continue;
    } finally {
      // Atribui valores aos elementos e insere no HTML
      result.appendChild(figure);
      add.href = "/add"; // AQUI EU ACESSO O @app.route no PYTHON
      figure.appendChild(add);
      img.src = cover;
      add.appendChild(img);
      figcap.innerHTML += `${title}<br>${author}`;
      add.appendChild(figcap);
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  result.innerHTML = "";
  search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&callback=handleResponse`;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Pesquise por título, autor, editora, lançamento, ISBN..." />
  <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para passar o parâmetro `book_id` no JavaScript para recebê-lo no Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar o book_id pela URL fazendo o seguinte:
`@app.route('/add/<int:book_id>')`

Dentro da sua função handleResponse altere para `` add.href = `/add/${item.book_id}` ``.

Estou assumindo que no item tem um atributo book_id, porque no seu codigo só encontrei cover, title, author.

Referência: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: O Python parece receber o parâmetro muito bem, O que você mostrou está certinho conforme a documentação, porém o JavaScript retornou 404. Daí percebi que eu deveria utilizar crase ao invés de aspas. Muito obrigado!!